# Can not use the function File.WriteAllText

Tags: c#, wpf

Simply put when I type File. in Visual Studio 2017 nothing comes up. Its like that function does not exist.

Background: I am trying to save the input the user types. The whole code should be correct because I copied it a turtorial website, an example from [www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-savefiledialog/]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow saveFileDialog = new MainWindow();
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)

            *I get a red squiggly line under File. and FileName.* 
         //File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, txtEditor.Text);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing

```
using System.IO;
```

at top of your cs file. Alternatively you could write

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText( saveFileDialog.FileName, txtEditor.Text );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Joel. Am I missing it beacause I choose the wrong when creating a new Project? Also how do i correct the FileName part, theres still an error there.

Comment: No, the IO namespace isn't a default using. You always have to add it manually.

Comment: You probably don't want to create a new MainWindow when you click a button on the MainWindow. It looks like you should be creating a [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. That class does have a FileName property. Also ShowDialog does not return a boolean.